# jQuery - Getting form values for ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to post form values via AJAX to a php file.  How do I collect my form values to send inside of the "data" parameter?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "submit=1&username="+username+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&passconf="+passconf,
        url: "http://rt.ja.com/includes/register.php",
        success: function(data)
        {   
            //alert(data);
            $('#userError').html(data);
            $("#userError").html(userChar);
            $("#userError").html(userTaken);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="border">
  <form  action="/" id="registerSubmit">
    <div id="userError"></div>
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10"/><br>
      <div id="emailError" ></div>
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="10" id="email"/><br>
      <div id="passError" ></div>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="10" id="password"/><br>
      <div id="passConfError" ></div>
      Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="passconf" size="10" id="passconf"/><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should send it in json format `{"key":value, "key":value}`. What i would suggest is create a javascript object with your parameters as its properties and use `JSON.stringify(object)` to convert the object into json format.

Comment: @SangSuantak, why would you bother with JSON conversions when you would not need them with the normal set of name/value pairs?!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use the serialize method:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $("#registerSubmit").serialize(),
    ...
})
```

Docs: [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: How do you get the form data and an extra manually set variable? like  data: $("#registerSubmit").serialize() + '&myvar=123' ? that doesn't seem to work the way I have it

Comment: I don't see what that wouldn't be working. If the data you want to append is more complex, you can use `$.param`. `$("form").serialize() + "&" + $.param({ myvar: 123 })`.

Comment: There's also another method: use `serializeArray`. `data = $("form").serializeArray(); data.push({ name: "myvar", value: 123 }); $.param(data);`

Comment: yes this was the ticket I figured out last night as well.. I had to manually add the + '&' + between each. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
$("#registerSubmit").serialize() // returns all the data in your form
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'your url',
     data: $("#registerSubmit").serialize(),
     success: function() {
          //success message mybe...
     }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use val function to collect data from inputs:

```
jQuery("#myInput1").val();
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Yeah, but you shouldn't have to do it manually for every field. That's what serialize is for. What if you add a field? You dont want to have to change your js.

Answer (score 6):

```
var data={
 userName: $('#userName').val(),
 email: $('#email').val(),
 //add other properties similarly
}
```

and

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://rt.ja.com/includes/register.php?submit=1",
        data: data

        success: function(html)
        {   
            //alert(html);
            $('#userError').html(html);
            $("#userError").html(userChar);
            $("#userError").html(userTaken);
        }
    });
```

You dont have to bother about anything else. jquery will handle the serialization etc. also you can append the submit query string parameter submit=1 into the data json object.

Answer (score 1):

try as this code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://rt.ja.com/includes/register.php?submit=1",
        data: "username="+username+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&passconf="+passconf,

        success: function(html)
        {   
            //alert(html);
            $('#userError').html(html);
            $("#userError").html(userChar);
            $("#userError").html(userTaken);
        }
    });
```

i think this will work definitely..

you can also use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function for sending data via jquery Ajax..

```
i.e: data : $("#registerSubmit").serialize()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var email= $('#email').val();
var password= $('#password').val();
```