# Why do I receive an empty email?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

Why are the field values not included in my email? I receive an empty email.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    beforeSend: function() {
      form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(6000).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php

$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$headers    = 'From:'. @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$temp_name  = 'Client name='.$name."\n\n\n";
$temp_text  = 'client query='.@trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$message    = $temp_name.$temp_text; 
$to         = 'svasu1850@gmail.com';

if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  $result="Thanks for contacting us";
}else{
  $result="retry after some time";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you silencing your PHP errors? Remove `@` and you ought to see some relevant error messages.

Comment: then also i dont get any error just i get an empty mail without the field values

Answer (score 1):

You are using your javascript to prevent the default form submission.  This stops the posting of the input from your user, unless you capture it and choose to send it along inside your ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
...
data: $("#main-contact-form").serialize(),
...
})
```

See more here: [jQuery - Getting form values for ajax POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426085/jquery-getting-form-values-for-ajax-post)