# Saving value from html input > date using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to save date using html input = date and ajax. but it didn't save.

html code:

```
<td class="dtreq"><input type="text" class="dtreq" name="dtreq" id="dtreq"></td>
```

Ajax:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
var dtreq = [];

$('.dtreq').each(function(){
    dtreq.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
      url:"insert_punchlist_form.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{dtreq:dtreq},
      success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
        $('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        for(var i=2; i<= count; i++){
          $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: `dtreq` is a same class for `td` and `input` ?? .. Also id should be unique don't use the same id for more than one element

Comment: i removed the class at input. still same.

Comment: if you removed the class from input you need to use `$(this).find('input').val()` because td doesn't have value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Getting form values for ajax POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426085/jquery-getting-form-values-for-ajax-post)

Comment: I have updated your code check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#save').click(function(){
var dtreq = [];

$('input.dtreq').each(function(){

    dtreq.push($(this).val());
    });
    
    console.log(dtreq);
    $.ajax({
      url:"insert_punchlist_form.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{dtreq:dtreq},
      success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
        $('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        for(var i=2; i<= count; i++){
          $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="dtreq"><input type="text" class="dtreq" name="dtreq" id="dtreq"></td>
<td class="dtreq"><input type="text" class="dtreq" name="test1" id="test1"></td>
<td class="dtreq"><input type="text" class="dtreq" name="test2" id="test2"></td>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: Good point, the selector `'input.dtreq'`! The importance of this could not be demonstrated in @RonakChauhan's answer, because the html is faulty: the `<td>`s are floating around without being in a proper table. Maybe you can fix this in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

data : { "dtrec" : dtrec }
the key in the data JSON object  should be quoted or else it is parsed as a variable and of course the variable dtrec of the value part of data JSON object should be serialized as valid json

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have modified your code please check.

```js
$('#save').click(function(){
var dtreq = [];

$('.dtreq').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    dtreq.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
      url:"insert_punchlist_form.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{dtreq:dtreq},
      success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
        $('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        for(var i=2; i<= count; i++){
          $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="dtreq"><input type="text" class="dtreq" name="dtreq" id="dtreq"></td>

<button id="save">Save</button>
```